# onchange event in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have two edit boxes in an XPage and one label.

Leave Start Date : EDIT BOX
Leave End Date   : EDIT Box
Holidays Taken    : label

I want to calulate the diffence in dates and get it computed in the label using the following code in onChange event of second(Leave End Date) edit box but on chaging the value of the edit box it clears the two field and nothing gets computed:

```
var leaveStartDate = document1.getValue("fld_Leave_Start_Date1");
var leaveEndDate = document1.getValue("fld_Leave_End_Date1");

var difference = null; 
try{
    var nDateStart = session.createDateTime( leaveStartDate  );
    var nDateEnd = session.createDateTime( leaveEndDate );

    difference = nDateEnd.timeDifference(nDateStart); 
    difference = (Math.floor(difference/86400)) + 1;

}catch(e)
{
    return e
}
document1.setValue("fld_NoOfDays",difference);
```

I tried getComponent("fld_Leave_Start_Date1").getSubmittedValue(), but didn't work either.
Can someone please help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please add details on your onChange event. Is it a partial refresh? and what component does it refresh?

Comment: There are only two times to use getSubmittedValue(). If you're using a validator and want to check the value of the component. Or if you've selected "Do not validate or update values" in the event properties for the partial refresh. All other places it will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

If the edit boxes are getting cleared, it sounds like you've set the event to do a full refresh instead of a partial refresh.

The other possible cause of clearing fields is if you're using Partial Execution Mode (execMode="Partial" in the source pane for the eventHandler) but have specified a execId that does not include the two edit boxes. (Partial Execution by default runs on the current component, so you should not lose the values of that Edit Box.) But I don't think that's the case.